# Conditional NULL SELECT

Tags: sql-server

What is the proper syntax to conditionally query value with the NULL check?

```
DECLARE @TargetDialogHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @EventMessage XML
DECLARE @EventMessageTypeName sysname

WAITFOR(
    RECEIVE @TargetDialogHandle = conversation_handle,
    @EventMessage = CONVERT(XML, message_body),
    @EventMessageTypeName = message_type_name FROM dbo.EventNotificationQueue ), TIMEOUT 1000

SELECT 
    @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TSQLCommand, 
    CASE @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') 
       WHEN NULL @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') 
       ELSE @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') 
    END AS TableName
```

This throws an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near '@EventMessage'.

The statement below:

```
DECLARE @TargetDialogHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @EventMessage XML
DECLARE @EventMessageTypeName sysname

WAITFOR(
    RECEIVE @TargetDialogHandle = conversation_handle,
    @EventMessage = CONVERT(XML, message_body),
    @EventMessageTypeName = message_type_name FROM dbo.EventNotificationQueue ), TIMEOUT 1000

SELECT 
    @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TSQLCommand, 
    IIF( @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') IS NULL, @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)'), @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)')) AS TableName
```

returns

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two styles for the `CASE` expression:

```
CASE (column name or SQL variable)
   WHEN (value 1) 
      THEN (return value 1)
   WHEN (value 2) 
      THEN (return value 2)       
   ELSE (return else value)
END
```

This checks if the column or variable name after `CASE` is equal to one of the given values and returns something in each case.

However, if you cannot check for equality - and with `NULL`, you **never** can! - you need to use the other style:

```
CASE 
   WHEN (expression 1) 
      THEN (return value 1)
   WHEN (expression 2) 
      THEN (return value 2)       
   ELSE (return else value)
END
```

So here you check formulate expressions (that can use something *other* than just equality checks - e.g. checks for >=, or with `BETWEEN` for ranges etc.).

In your case, since you want to check for `NULL`, you **must** use approach #2:

```
SELECT 
    @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TSQLCommand, 
    CASE 
       -- check if your value IS NULL
       WHEN @EventMessage.value(.....) IS NULL 
          THEN @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') 
       ELSE @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)') 
    END AS TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

```
DECLARE @TargetDialogHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @EventMessage XML
DECLARE @EventMessageTypeName sysname

WAITFOR(
    RECEIVE @TargetDialogHandle = conversation_handle,
    @EventMessage = CONVERT(XML, message_body),
    @EventMessageTypeName = message_type_name FROM dbo.EventNotificationQueue ), TIMEOUT 1000

SELECT 
    @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS TSQLCommand, 
    COALESCE(@EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)'), @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)')) AS TableName
```

Comment: quoting the link you gave: `The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression. That is, the code COALESCE(expression1,...n) is rewritten by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression: `. So why use the syntactic sugar when I can go straight to the source?